# How does this code that tests for a system's Endianess work?

Tags: memory, system

So I'm trying to find out what endianess a system is using by using code. I looked on the net, and found someone with the same question, and one of the answers on Stack Exchange had the following code:

```
int num = 1;
if(*(char *)&num == 1)
{
    printf("\nLittle-Endian\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Big-Endian\n");
}
```

But the person did not explain why this works, and I could not ask. What the reasoning behind the following code?

```
(*(char *)&num == 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using C/C++

1. `&num` takes the address in memory of the integer `num`.
2. It interprets that address as a pointer to a `char` by the cast
   `(char *)`
3. Next, the value of this pointer to a char is considered by the first asterix in `*(char *)&num` and compared
   to 1.

Now `int` is 4 bytes. It would be `00 00 00 01` on a big endian system and `01 00 00 00` on little endian system. A char is only one byte, so the the value of the cast to char would take the first byte of the memory occupied by `num`. So on a big endian system this would be `**00** 00 00 01` and on the little endian system this would be `**01** 00 00 00`.
So now you do the comparison using the if statement to found out whether the int, casted to a char, is equivalent to the order of bytes used on a little endian system.

On a X86 32bit system this could compile to the following assembly

```
mov     [esp+20h+var_4], 1      ; Moves the value of 1 to a memory address
lea     eax, [esp+20h+var_4]    ; Loads that memory address to eax register
mov     al, [eax]               ; Takes the first byte of the value pointed to by the eax register and move that to register al (al is 1 byte)
cmp     al, 1                   ; compares that one byte of register al to the value of 1
```

Comment: I like your answer and I understand now, but I have one more question, why is one byte represented as two zeros in your example? My original thought was that one byte would be represented as 8 zeros?

Comment: @ Rouke as its easy to think of a byte as in the range of 00 to 0xFF in hex value. When you are working with disassemblers you get to see CPU registers formatted in hex value, not in decimal values. Because the CPU takes the first byte (the cast to `char`), of a value (`int`) spanning 4 bytes, in your code, its easier to imagine what is actually happening this way.

Comment: @Rouke `My original thought was that one byte would be represented as 8 zeros` one byte has 8 bits. So if you would display one byte in binary you would indeed have 00000000 (eight) positions. Each 0 can be a 1 so the maximum value could be 11111111 which is 0xFF in hex and 255 in decimal. So `int num` would be written **binary** in 4 blocks of 8 bits, with the value of 1 it would be `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(*(char *)&num == 1)
```

Roughly translates as Take the address of variable `num`. Cast it's contents to a character and compare the value with 1.

If the character at the first address of your integer is 1 then it's the low-order byte, and your numbers are Little-Endian.

Big-Endian numbers will have the high-order byte (0 if the integer value is 1) at the lowest address, so the comparison will fail.

Answer (score 0):

we all know that type "int" occupies 4 bytes while "char" is only 1 byte. 
that line just converts the integer to a char.it is equivalent to : char c = (char)"the lowest byte of num".

see the concept of endianess: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

then if the host machine is big-endian, the value of c will be 0, and 1 otherwise.

an example is :
 suppose num is 0x12345678, on big-endian machines, c will be 0x12 whereas on little-endian machines c is 0x78

Answer (score 0):

Here goes. You assign the value 1 to a 4 byte int so

01 00 00 00 on little endian x86
00 00 00 01 on big endian

(*(char *)&num == 1)

&num gives the address of the int but the cast to char* restricts the read (the de-reference) to 1 byte (size of char)

If the first byte is 1 then the least significant bit went first and it's little endian.